# Using a global variable versus calling the function that returns said variable repeatedly

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a Python module which consists of a number of different functions.

Say my first function returns a variable which I want to use twice in the second and the second returns a variable which I want to use four times in the third function ( . . . and so on).

Is it better to declare the variables that I will want to use throughout the entire module as global and then call the function that returns said variable once to define it globally rather than to call functions more than once in order to use the variables they return?

Am I correct in saying that this is a trade-off between safety (not using global variables) and efficiency (not executing each function more than once if possible)?

```
    def fn_for_reading_file():
      # (Insert code for prompting user for filename, opening and reading file)
      global file_as_string
      # (Insert code for assigning user's file to file_as_string)
      return file_as_string

    fn_for_reading_file()

    def extract_data_from_string():
      global my_list = []
      # (Insert code for going through return_file_as_string and appending data to my_list)
      return my_list

    extract_data_from_string()

    def another_fn():
      # (Insert code which uses file_as_string and my_list)
      return fn_output

    another_fn()
```

Comment: Could you provide a less abstract example? Why can't you store the returned value within the calling function? If the functions are pure, memoization can make repeated calls more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to reframe the problem you're thinking about. If you're only thinking in terms of functional programming then yes, you're correct in that safety vs. more code is the basic trade off you're looking at.

However, there are a number of ways to get around your dilemma by reframing the problem. I obviously don't know what your code looks like, but it might be meaningful to think about building this functionality into a class. Rather than using global variables, set those values as class attributes with appropriate getters/setters, and then structure the module such that your functions become methods.

Comment: Problem solved by re-framing in the context of a class and using class attributes. Thank you.